# Pagecolor, fancypagestyle and absolute positioning

Tags: color

I am trying to change the pagecolor on a title page, defined within a fancypagestyle. That works fine. I am also using absolute positioning to place text boxes on this title page, I redifne the \maketitle command. My problem is that none of the textblocks show up on the title page.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./graphics/}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{21.2cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.05cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.05cm}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}

\newcommand{\cth}{\small CTH~}
\newcommand{\cale}{\small CALE~}
\newcommand{\theBattelleTitle}{}
\newcommand{\theclient}{}
\newcommand{\theReportDate}{}
\newcommand{\thedisclaimer}{}
\newcommand{\theTechnical}{}
\newcommand{\theBusiness}{}


\newcommand{\BattelleTitle}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theBattelleTitle}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\client}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theclient}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\ReportDate}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theReportDate}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\disclaimer}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thedisclaimer}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\Technical}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theTechnical}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\Business}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theBusiness}{#1}
}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\definecolor{BattelleBlue}{RGB}{0,85,150}
\definecolor{White}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\fancypagestyle{fancyBattelle}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhfoffset{30mm}
    \setlength{\voffset}{-10mm}
    \setlength{\footskip}{20mm}
    %\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=208mm]{BattelleTitle.jpg}}
    %\fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[width=208mm]{BattelleFooter.png}\\ \thepage}
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \clearpage
    \pagestyle{fancyBattelle}
    \mbox{}
    \pagecolor{BattelleBlue}%\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\begin{textblock}{5.5}(1.1667,1.5)
    \noindent{\textcolor{White}{\textsf{\bf{\LARGE{\theBattelleTitle}}}}}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{7}(1.1667,2.5)
    \noindent{\textsf{\Large{Battelle Memorial Institute \\ 505 King Avenue \\ Columbus, OH  43201}}}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{7}(1.1667,3.5)
    \noindent{\textsf{\Large{To: \\ \theclient}}}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{2}(1.1667,4.25)
    \noindent{\textsf{\large{\theReportDate}}}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{2}(1.1667,5)
    \noindent{\textsf{\bf Battelle Technical Contact:} \\ \theTechnical}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{2}(4.0,5.0)
    \noindent{\textsf{\bf Battelle Contracts Contact:} \\ \theBusiness}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{5.5}(0.8333,7.0)
    \noindent{\thedisclaimer}
\end{textblock}
\newpage
}



\begin{document}

\BattelleTitle{Modeling/Simulation of Novel Concept Explosive Device}

\client{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\ReportDate{April 2014}

\Technical{Dr. Michael Fisher \\ Research Leader \\ (614) 424-7871 \\ (614) 458-7871 (fax) \\ fisherml@battelle.org}

\Business{Myriah Denk \\ Contracting Officer \\ (919) 544-9154 \\ (614) 458-0291 (fax) \\ denkm@battelle.org}

\disclaimer{This proposal or quotation includes data that shall not be disclosed outside the government and shall not be duplicated, used, or disclosed-in whole or in part-for any purpose other than to evaluate this proposal or quotation.  If, however, a contract is awarded to this offeror or quoter as a result of-or in connection with-the submission of this data, the government shall have the right to duplicate, use, or disclose the data to the extent provided in the resulting contract.  This restriction does not limit the government's right to use information contained in this data if it is obtained from another source without restriction.  The data subject to this restriction are contained in all pages of this proposal.}

\maketitle

\section{\textcolor{White}{Introduction}}


\section{Technical Approach}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=6in.]{admodel_0001.png}
    \caption{\small{AUTODYN}\textsuperscript{\textregistered} model at time $t = 0$ for a novel concept explosive device similar to the FBI device. The model has axial symmetry and is shown here rotated 180$^\circ$ about the axis of symmetry. The device casing is aluminum (blue color), the shaped charge jet liner and the EFP are copper (green), the wave shaper is concrete (cyan), and the HE is Comp C-4, (red).}
    \label{initial}
\end{figure}

\section{Deliverables}


\section{Program Schedule and ROM Costs}



\end{document}
```

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The problem with your construction is that, right now, you have no elements on the page that are recognised as such, everything is basically watermarked on the first page. Your workaround of using `\mbox{}` won't work here since pagecolor is added at the very shipout of the page, at which point your other watermarked objects are already in the input stream and therefore typeset before pagecolor is. A solution is pending (no promises yet though).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a new macro for you using `tikz`.

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\placetext[3][2cm]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west,text width=\textwidth,align=left ]
  at ([xshift=#1,yshift=-#2]current page.north west) {#3};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

In this, I have kept the default horizontal shift as `2cm`. If you want to change it, use the optional argument. The syntax is

```
\placetext[x shift]{yshift}{%
    content
}
xshift default 2cm, and yshift is downwards
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./graphics/}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{21.2cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.05cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.05cm}
%\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
%\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}

\newcommand{\cth}{\small CTH~}
\newcommand{\cale}{\small CALE~}
\newcommand{\theBattelleTitle}{}
\newcommand{\theclient}{}
\newcommand{\theReportDate}{}
\newcommand{\thedisclaimer}{}
\newcommand{\theTechnical}{}
\newcommand{\theBusiness}{}


\newcommand{\BattelleTitle}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theBattelleTitle}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\client}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theclient}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\ReportDate}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theReportDate}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\disclaimer}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thedisclaimer}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\Technical}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theTechnical}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\Business}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theBusiness}{#1}
}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\definecolor{BattelleBlue}{RGB}{0,85,150}
\definecolor{White}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\fancypagestyle{fancyBattelle}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhfoffset{30mm}
    \setlength{\voffset}{-10mm}
    \setlength{\footskip}{20mm}
    %\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=208mm]{BattelleTitle.jpg}}
    %\fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[width=208mm]{BattelleFooter.png}\\ \thepage}
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\placetext[3][2cm]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west,text width=\textwidth,align=left ]
  at ([xshift=#1,yshift=-#2]current page.north west) {#3};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \clearpage
    \pagestyle{fancyBattelle}
    \mbox{}
    \pagecolor{BattelleBlue}%\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\placetext{5cm}{%
    \textcolor{White}{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE \theBattelleTitle}
    }
\placetext{8cm}{%
    \sffamily\Large Battelle Memorial Institute \\ 505 King Avenue \\ Columbus, OH  43201\par}
%\begin{textblock}{7}(1.1667,3.5)
%    \noindent{\textsf{\Large{To: \\ \theclient}}}
%\end{textblock}
%\begin{textblock}{2}(1.1667,4.25)
%    \noindent{\textsf{\large{\theReportDate}}}
%\end{textblock}
%\begin{textblock}{2}(1.1667,5)
%    \noindent{\textsf{\bf Battelle Technical Contact:} \\ \theTechnical}
%\end{textblock}
\placetext[4cm]{15cm}{%
    \sffamily\bfseries Battelle Contracts Contact: \\ \theBusiness
}
%\begin{textblock}{5.5}(0.8333,-7.0)
%    \noindent\thedisclaimer
%\end{textblock}
%Some text
\newpage
}


\begin{document}


\BattelleTitle{Modeling/Simulation of Novel Concept Explosive Device}

\client{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\ReportDate{April 2014}

\Technical{Dr. Michael Fisher \\ Research Leader \\ (614) 424-7871 \\ (614) 458-7871 (fax) \\ fisherml@battelle.org}

\Business{Myriah Denk \\ Contracting Officer \\ (919) 544-9154 \\ (614) 458-0291 (fax) \\ denkm@battelle.org}

\disclaimer{This proposal or quotation includes data that shall not be disclosed outside the government and shall not be duplicated, used, or disclosed-in whole or in part-for any purpose other than to evaluate this proposal or quotation.  If, however, a contract is awarded to this offeror or quoter as a result of-or in connection with-the submission of this data, the government shall have the right to duplicate, use, or disclose the data to the extent provided in the resulting contract.  This restriction does not limit the government's right to use information contained in this data if it is obtained from another source without restriction.  The data subject to this restriction are contained in all pages of this proposal.}

\maketitle

\section{\textcolor{White}{Introduction}}


\section{Technical Approach}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=6in.]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\small{AUTODYN}\textsuperscript{\textregistered} model at time $t = 0$ for a novel concept explosive device similar to the FBI device. The model has axial symmetry and is shown here rotated 180$^\circ$ about the axis of symmetry. The device casing is aluminum (blue color), the shaped charge jet liner and the EFP are copper (green), the wave shaper is concrete (cyan), and the HE is Comp C-4, (red).}
    \label{initial}
\end{figure}

\section{Deliverables}


\section{Program Schedule and ROM Costs}



\end{document}
```

[image]

I have modified only a few entries for this macro. Rest is an assignment for you.

## Notes

1. Don't use `\sf` `\bf` etc. All these two letter commands are deprecated. Use `\sffamily`, `\bfseries` etc.
2. `\noindent` doesn't take an argument, so `\noindent{...}` is wrong.
3. Similarly `\bf{...}`, `\Large{...}` etc, is wrong. `\bfseries` is a switch, not a command.
4. Occasionaly add a `\par` at the end, so that line spacing etc are correct.

A sample of correct usage is

```
    \placetext{8cm}{%
        \sffamily\Large Battelle Memorial Institute \\ 505 King Avenue \\ Columbus,
        OH  43201\par
      }
```